# Change the output of wp_title()

Tags: wp-title

I use wp_title to generate some kind of breadcrumb and it works well, but in there I have the title of the *site*, and I want to delete that. It looks like this:

Taxonomy1: City | Title of the site. I get that by using `<?php wp_title(); ?>`.

How can I delete the title of the site in that output?

Comment: Have you read this? http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in header.php of your theme. Some themes have the title output like this:

```
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?> | <?php echo get_bloginfo('name') ?></title>
```

So you'll have to remove the `| <?php echo get_bloginfo('name') ?>` part.

However you should keep the title of the site in the `<title>` for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a third-party filter running on the `wp_title`. Remove it before you call the function:

```
remove_all_filters( 'wp_title' );
wp_title();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like WordPress SEO by Yoast and set templates for so if your title tags. You would then have the ability to override your templates at the post/page/category level